# Adding two latex variables in Tikz beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to add two `latex` variables in a Tikz environment in a beamer presentation, but it's not working for me. Here is my example where I get: `i+j=4+17` instead of `i+j=21`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\title{Some Title}
\author{greatest author out there}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Adding two integers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \i {4}
\def \j {17}
\draw (0,0) node{\tiny{i+j = \i+\j}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `\the\numexpr\i+\j`. This works regardless of whether or not you have loaded Ti*k*Z. (And use math mode and `\scriptstyle` instead of `\tiny`.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\title{Some Title}
\author{greatest author out there}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Adding two integers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \i {4}
\def \j {17}
\draw (0,0) node{$\scriptstyle i+j =\the\numexpr\i+\j$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\title{Some Title}
\author{greatest author out there}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Adding two integers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \i {4}
\def \j {17}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ij{\i+\j}
\draw (0,0) node{\tiny i+j = \ij};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You have to tell `tikz/pgf` to calculate the result first ... This is what `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` does here.

PS: See also `\pgfmathsetmacro`

Answer (score 4):

tikz does not know that you want the sum, you need to tell it with `\pgfmathparse`

`\tiny{...}` is wrong. It should be `{\tiny ...}`, but better use the tikz key `font=\tiny`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\title{Some Title}
\author{greatest author out there}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Adding two integers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \i {4}
\def \j {17}

\draw (0,0) node[font=\tiny] {i+j =\pgfmathparse{\i+\j}\pgfmathresult };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

You can use `\pgfmathparse` and related expressions. Please see section 94 (Mathematical Expressions) of the current TikZ documentation for more details and examples.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Adding two integers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \i {4}
\def \j {17}
\draw (0,0) node{\tiny{i+j = \pgfmathparse{\i+\j}\pgfmathresult}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `\pgfmathsetmacro`;  and (very flexible) node option `[scale=5]`, `[scale=.5]`, etc instead of `\tiny`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Adding two integers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\i{4}
\def\j{17}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{int(\i+\j)}
\path (0,0) node[scale=5]{$i+j=\s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```